# How can I use a blue yeti on iPad Pro while still being able to her the audio output from the built in speakers?

Tags: ios, ipad, ipados

I have to record myself for music lessons over zoom. I need a better input than the built in mic but I still need to be able to hear the person on the other end. Is there a way I could use a blue yeti but still be able to hear the audio output from my iPad?

Comment: Have you contacted Blue Designs, the maker of the Yeti, to ask them about this?

Comment: @fsb Not yet. I do not have the mic yet but I am considering different ways to get it to work. The yeti just seems like the best option to me but it’s not set in stone.

Comment: We're not product support for these companies so if you have questions on how they work you should reach out to them directly.  If your question is about how to perform something on Apple products, you can ask them here.  See [ask] for more info.